# Node.js post request on http not finishing

Tags: node.js, http

In node.js I am using the http request module to make this request

```
var post_req = http.request({
    host: 'api.site1.ciscozeus.io',
    path: '/logs/' + ZUES_TOKEN + '/' + logName + '/',
    port: 80,
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Content-type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    }
}, function(res) {
    res.on('data', function (chunk) {
        console.log(1);
        cb(chunk);
    });
});
post_req.write(JSON.stringify({
    "logs" : JSON.stringify('[{"test":"value1"}]')
}));
post_req.on('error', function(e) {
    console.error(e);
});
post_req.end();
```

But I am the problem is it doesn't seem to go into `cb(chunk);`. Like it doesn't call the end promise function. It doesn't print console.log(1).

The api has a test site with a try it out, and if I try it there, it works. Here is how the logs data looks when I inspect it when it works in that tool:

[image]
[image]

Does anyone know if I am attaching the logs data incorrectly? I wan't to post the same data.

Thanks

Comment: Don't need to call JSON.stringify() on something that is already a string. Your request is probably malformed. Listen for res.on('err',...) and see if that gives you a clue.

Answer (score 0):

```
post_req.write(JSON.stringify({
    "logs" : JSON.stringify('[{"test":"value1"}]')
}));
```

in the above part of the code the internal `JSON.stringify` is incorrect. you should just write `'logs' : [{'test' : 'value1'}]`. The outer `JSON.stringify` will take care of converting entire JSON `object` to `string`.